# Retrigger OnCreate() method of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, oncreate

Is it possible to retrigger the `OnCreate()` method of the `Activity`we're returning to, after finishing the activity we're currently on ?

I've tried the `startActivityForResult()` method, but this isn't a good solution as it messes the `backstack` of the activities.

Also, I can't use the `onResume()` method of the activity as the function I need to do (a theme change) can only be done on `onCreate()` to work properly.

Any suggestions on this ? Am I missing something ? Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully if you call returning activity via intent after finishing current activity if will call onCreate() method.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why you want to re create your activity.
But i think calling this method could help you :

```
reCreate();
```

From [http://developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29)

> public void recreate () Added in API level 11
>
> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results
>   in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a
>   configuration change -- the current instance will go through its
>   lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

You can also try this way:

```
 startActivity(getIntent());
 finish();
```

Comment: I need to recreate the activity because I need to change the theme. And If I change the theme and I go back to this activity, the theme change has no effect. Only when it gets recreated, the theme change applies to the activity.

Comment: this method will restart your activity and its life cycle . i calling reCreate() will help you . try it and let me know the result :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't get called when returning to the activity.

Comment: As I said, the recreate() doesn't get triggered when returning to the activity after finishing the current activity.

Comment: in your onActivityResult call it ! its work . i used it in the same case and worked for me :)

Comment: I can't call it there, as onActivityResult() only gets called if I use the startActivityForResult() in the activity I want to finish. And this isn't a good approach, as I said, because it messes the backstack of the activities.

Comment: you can save your current theme name in a variable and in your onResume chack it. if this field not equal with new theme name call reCreate();

Comment: Yes, but if I use this approach, I will mess the backstack again, as I don't need to finish the activity.

Comment: what you need from backstack ? use `onSaveInstanceState` and save them if you lose data

Comment: It's not about losing data, it's about returning to the wright activity when the back button is pressed. If i finish the activity, this one will get skipped when the back is pressed, and I don't need that.

Comment: i tell you about how to avoid losing data ! i think recreate() is the best way you can find.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if we call onCreate() from onActivityResult() method directly.

But this is not advisable to break Activity Life-cycle of Android

> If you really want to do some useful task in onCreate() then you can
>   do that in onResume() method

From your requirement, i understand that you want to set new theme to your activity view after child activity is finished.

For this case, you can use **Fragment**. You just need to add a new fragment in `onResume()` method

> 1. For Fragment creation : [How to create Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
> 2. In onResume(), replace `content_frame` with new Fragment in which you need theme changes

**UPDATE** :

From your **MainActivity.java** :

```
startActivityForResult( /* parameters for calling SecondActivity*/ );
finish();
```

This way, your calling activity (which is MainActivity.java) is finished. So, when SecondActivity is finished, **focus will come to onActivityResult() of MainActivity.java and onCreate() will also be called** because it was finished

Comment: Yes I know. As i mentioned, I tried this approach, but It messed the activity lifecycle and indeed is not a good recommended solution.

Comment: No, it only works properly on onCreate() method, before calling the super constructor.

Comment: It should not be the case. can you paste your code ?

Comment: public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
  switch (sTheme) {
  default:
  case THEME_DEFAULT:
   activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
   break;
  case THEME_2:
   activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
   break; }}

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but the fragment takes the theme of the activity it is attached to. So if I can't change the activity's theme, the fragment will still have the same theme.

Comment: Please check my update in answer. It will solve your problem and work

Comment: I followed my first approach with the startActivityForResult() method (kinda like what you UPDATE-d in you response) and I override the onBackStack() functions of some activities. It's the only way I could have done this. But this works only for that specific activity, hopefully I don't need to integrate it in other activities, as this solution will never work because I can only get back to a specific activity with the startActivityForResult() method. But, if this is the only solution, it works for now.